# Handling multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a $row array value like this.

```
    Array
    (
            [123] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [author_name] => A1
                            [book_name] => A1B1
                            [rating] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [author_name] => A1
                            [book_name] => A1B2
                            [rating] => 5.5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [author_name] => A1
                            [book_name] => A1B3
                            [rating] => 5.7
                        )
                )


                [456] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [author_name] => A2
                            [book_name] => A2B1
                            [rating] => 7
                        )
                  )     
    )
```

I need to display the above array values like this.

```
    Author Code         Author Name     Book Name       Rating
    123                 A1              A1B1            5   
                                        AlB2            5.5
                                        A1B3            5.7

    456                 A2              A2B1            7
```

I'm new to array concepts, and now I'm able to fetch the array alone.
Any php code will be of great help.

Comment: Start from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

Comment: you may use nested foreach loops and check what an array is. it's quite easy anyway, have you tried something yet?

Comment: my array concept is very ugly. some code would help me. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what other ways (or options) to print something like that, but alternatively, you can also restructure it. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$original_values = array(
    123 => array(
        array('author_name' => 'A1', 'book_name' => 'A1B1', 'rating' => 5),
        array('author_name' => 'A1', 'book_name' => 'A1B3', 'rating' => 5.5),
        array('author_name' => 'A1', 'book_name' => 'A1B1', 'rating' => 5.7),
    ),
    456 => array(
        array('author_name' => 'A2', 'book_name' => 'A2B1', 'rating' => 7),
    ),
);

$formatted_values = array();
foreach($original_values as $id => $array1) {
    foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
        $formatted_values[$id][$value['author_name']][] = array('name' => $value['book_name'], 'rating' => $value['rating']);
    }
}

?>

<table cellpadding="10">
    <thead><tr><th>Author Code</th><th>Book Name</th><th>Book Name</th><th>Rating</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($formatted_values as $author_code => $value): ?>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><?php echo $author_code; ?></td>
            <?php foreach($value as $author_name => $books): ?>
                <td><?php echo $author_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php foreach($books as $book_info): ?><?php echo $book_info['name']; ?><br/><?php endforeach; ?></td>
                <td><?php foreach($books as $book_info): ?><?php echo $book_info['rating']; ?><br/><?php endforeach; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fV56Lp)

Comment: exactly. this one. thanks a ton. please upvote my question ;(